# Converting hex to little endian in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, endianness

I have a hex number which is represented like this

Hex num:

```
b'95b64fc1830100'
```

How could I converted to little endian so it could be shown like this?

```
00000183C14FB695
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the trick (input is hex):

```
hex_num = b'95b64fc1830100'
big = bytearray.fromhex(str(hex_num, 'utf-8'))
big.reverse()
little = ''.join(f"{n:02X}" for n in big)
print(little)
```

This prints:

```
000183C14FB695
```

The output is a string, if you want to get the result back to bytes you can add the following lines:

```
hex_bytes= bytearray(int(little, 16).to_bytes(8, 'big')).hex()
print(hex_bytes)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that my variable is in hex format and not in string. So if I use your solution I am getting the following error: TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: This is not a problem, I've slightly modified my code to work with a hex input/output.